# submeter formulário a partir de uma select

Tags: php, html

Tenho uma `<select>` com várias opções, ao ao selecionar uma opção, quero que o formulário seja submetido para a mesma página e vou buscar o valor por php na mesma página. Para isso, tenho o seguinte:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['select_carros']))
    {
         echo $_POST['select_carros'];
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post" name="menuForm">
     <select name="select_carros">
          <option value="1">Carro 1</option>
          <option value="2">Carro 2</option>
          <option value="3">Carro 3</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Basicamente, o que quero é que ao escolher a opção seja imprimido o valor dessa opção. Por exemplo, escolho a opção "Carro 2" e vai ser imprimido "2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Exemplo Completo com Seleção da Última escolha:*

```
<form action="" method="post" name="menuForm">
     <select name="select_carros" onchange="document.forms['menuForm'].submit();">
         <option value="0">Escolha a Opção</option>
          <option value="1" <?php echo isset($_POST['select_carros']) && $_POST['select_carros']==1?' selected="selected"':'';?>>Carro 1</option>
          <option value="2" <?php echo isset($_POST['select_carros']) && $_POST['select_carros']==2?' selected="selected"':'';?>>Carro 2</option>
          <option value="3" <?php echo isset($_POST['select_carros']) && $_POST['select_carros']==3?' selected="selected"':'';?>>Carro 3</option>
     </select>
</form>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['select_carros']))
    {
         echo $_POST['select_carros'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

É só usar o onChange :

```
<form action="" method="post" name="menuForm" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

Answer (score 0):

O action do seu form deve ser submetido para a mesma página, para que você consiga pegar o valor "2" no $_POST['select_carros'].

```
<form action="mesma_pagina.php" method="post" name="menuForm">
```

Comment: sim, mas já está a ser submetido para a mesma página.

Comment: Então utilize o onChange="this.form.submit();" no <form>.